# ezdxf python mtext set location

Tags: python, dxf, ezdxf

I have some simple text I want to place in my dxf, like this:

```
mtext = msp.add_mtext("TEXT TEST", dxfattribs={'style': 'OpenSans'})
```

I want to insert this text in `x=1` and `y=1` location in my dxf.

This is what i tried:

```
mtext.dxf.insert([1,1,0])
```

But I get error:

```
mtext.dxf.insert([1,1,0])
TypeError: 'Vector' object is not callable
```

Any help in resolving this is appreciated.

**Edit:**

When working with single line text like:

```
mtext = msp.add_text("TEXT TEST").set_pos((1, 2),align='MIDDLE_RIGHT')
```

Everything works fine, but I still need to have multiline text written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All DXF attributes inside the `MText.dxf` namespace act like regular object attributes, in this case setting the `MText.dxf.insert` attribute looks like this:

```
mtext.dxf.insert = (1, 1, 0)
```

The extended placement method is called `MText.set_location()`:

```
mtext.set_location(insert=(1, 1, 0), rotation=0, attachment_point=1)
```

For more information look at the [documentation](https://ezdxf.mozman.at/docs/dxfentities/mtext.html) or the [MTEXT tutorial](https://ezdxf.mozman.at/docs/tutorials/mtext.html).